# Passing variable to input type text Laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I want to make a filter in the text field where, after entering the user's id number, his bookings are displayed. I need to use a MySQL procedure for this.

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GetUserBookings`(IN p_userId INT)
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM bookings
    WHERE userId = p_userId;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I have a problem with Undefined variable $userId. This line is selected: `<form action="{{ route('booking.GetUserBookings', ['userId' => $userId]) }}" method="get">`

Controller Function:

```
public function GetUserBookings(Request $request) : View
{
    $userId = $request->input('userId');
    $results = DB::select('CALL GetUserBookings(?)', [$userId]);
    return view('booking.GetUserBookings', [
        'bookings' => $results,
        'userId' => $userId
    ]);
}
```

Routing:

```php
Route::get("/booking/GetUserBookings/{userId}", [BookingController::class, 'GetUserBookings'])
    ->name('booking.GetUserBookings');
```

View:

```html
<form action="{{ route('booking.GetUserBookings', ['userId' => $userId]) }}" method="get">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="text" name="userId" value="{{ request()->input('userId') }}" placeholder="Enter User ID Number">
    <button type="submit">Filter</button>
</form>
```

And if I enter the URL: `/booking/GetUserBookings/3` then the website works and I see bookings

Comment: So.. are you have error or website works? I don't get it. Error in SQL or with passing data in variable?

Comment: Passing data in variable

Answer (score 2):

Form action submit is associated to a POST method, change it in your Routes

```
Route::post("/booking/GetUserBookings/{userId}", [BookingController::class, 'GetUserBookings'])
->name('booking.GetUserBookings');
```

Or change to an anchor Link, and in the controller change the

> GetUserBookings(Request $request)

to

```
public function GetUserBookings(userId) : View
{
    $results = DB::select('CALL GetUserBookings(?)', [$userId]);
    return view('booking.GetUserBookings', [
        'bookings' => $results,
        'userId' => $userId
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately still not working